# Automated deployment to azure using wix installer

Tags: azure, powershell, wix, windows-installer, azure-web-app-service

I have a wix installer project which installs my Web API (c#) project into local IIS. Are there any out of the box support facility for installing a web API as Azure Web app on Azure using WIX installer? If the answer is no, are there any existing powershell scripts for automating the task partially or entirely?

Comment: Are you wanting to do lift and shift IaaS or PaaS?

Comment: Its a semi-[lift & shit] IaaS meaning the API remains the same, however the database will be migrated to SQL Azure from on-premise SQL Server. No redesign of the API or its internals are required at this stage.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, just deploy a Windows VM to Azure, install IIS and run your MSI to install your application.

Comment: I would like to deploy hosted API as App Service. Currently I do this manually by creating the app service then uploading the binaries. Ideally I would like the installer to do entire process for me.

Comment: Azure App Service is PaaS not IaaS.  WiX isn't really going to have much if any role to play.  I would look into Azure DevOps pipelines and tasks built for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to run it in a Windows Container Web App in Azure App Service.

Here is the info on how to Run a custom Windows container in Azure App Service:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-windows-container

You will need to run your wix installer as part of the dockerfile, just make sure you wait for the installer to complete